# How to insert multiple row in database table?

Tags: foreach

I want to insert multiple row in single table using foreach.

```
<pre  class='code'>Array
(
    [instructor_id] => 76
    [vehicle_id] => 2
    [arr_bookings] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 07-10-2016
                [1] => 1:10 PM
                [2] => 2:02 PM
                [3] => s
                [4] => s
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 07-10-2016
                [1] => 1:15 PM
                [2] => 2:01 PM
                [3] => a
                [4] => a
            )

    )

)
```

my result is this in print_r($result). how can i insert using foreach? any ideas about this.

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like.

`$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (column_1, column_2) VALUES";`

Then loop through your array like,

```
$last_key = end(array_keys($array));

foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
    // Don't forget to protect against SQL injection.
    $sql .= "('$value[0]', '$value[1]')";

    if ( $last_key === $key ) {
        $sql .= ",";
    }
}
```

After that you should have a sql statement that looks something like `INSERT INTO table_name (column_1, column_2) VALUES ('Some Value', 'Another Value'), ('foo', 'bar')`.